# NGINX: Lots of connection timed out Errors

Tags: nginx

I am getting this error a lot:

2014/11/26 21:01:30 [error] 3475#0: *4028 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream

Here is my configuration:

```
user www-data;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes 2;
worker_rlimit_nofile 16384;

events {
  worker_connections    4096;
  use                   epoll;
  multi_accept          on;
}

http {

  sendfile              on;
  tcp_nopush            on;
  tcp_nodelay           on;
  keepalive_timeout     65;

  # free up connection after client stops responding...
  reset_timedout_connection on;

  # If the client stops reading data, free up the stale client connection after this much time. Default 60.
  # send_timeout          2;


  types_hash_max_size   2048;

  server_names_hash_bucket_size 256;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;

  include               /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type          application/octet-stream;

  ssl_protocols         TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;  # don’t use SSLv3 ref: POODLE
  ssl_ciphers           "AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip                  on;
  gzip_vary             on;
  gzip_min_length       10240;
  gzip_proxied          expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types            text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
  gzip_disable          "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  ##
  # general proxy settings
  ##
  proxy_cache_path      /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=one:8m max_size=3000m inactive=600m;
  proxy_temp_path       /var/tmp;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;

  include               /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include               /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: please also post the content from the files in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

Comment: Increase `proxy_read_timeout` or check why your proxied backend doens't answer in time.

Comment: @XavierLucas increasing proxy_read_timeout got rid of the errors completely, but looking into the underlying cause seems important as well. It turns out most of these connections are WebSocket connections that are not being treated as such by nginx. I have just found in the documentation that you need to add an "Upgrade" header to force nginx to treat proxied connections as WebSockets. Do you know about this? I'm curious if adding this header will affect my non-websocket connetions negatively...

Comment: @AllTheTime Check my full answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution for the former issue** : increase `proxy_read_timeout` or check why your backend doens't answer in time.

**Your second question** : There are two things, the `Upgrade` header and the `Connection` header.

Both of these need to be passed to the backend when using websockets and you can use a map to change the value depending on original request headers (i.e. if it's a websocket connection handhaske or standard HTTP traffic). The backend must reply to the `Upgrade` header with HTTP `101`. Then nginx will enter in a specific case where a tunnel is set up between the origin of the request and the backend.

Such a case is explained in the [official documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html) :

> ```
> http {
>
>     map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
>         default     upgrade;
>         ''          close;
>     }
>
> }
>
> server {
>
>    ...
>
>    location /foo/ {
>         proxy_pass http://backend;
>         proxy_http_version 1.1;
>         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
>         proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
>     }
>
> }
> ```